# Looping through dynamically created TextBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a single page application that uses Reflection to create TextBoxes based on parameters from methods located in a .dll.

```
  @*Creates text boxes with parameters*@
  @{ var methodParameters = aMethod.GetParameters();}

  @{ foreach (var param in methodParameters)
    {
        <h3>@param.Name</h3>
        @Html.TextBox(param.Name)

    }}
```

That works fine. Next, I need to get the values out of the textboxes after the user enters a value and perform a calculation with those values. 
Again with reflection.

```
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" /> 

    @{ var invokeMethod = aMethod.Invoke(aMethod, new object[] {  surfacePower, lensDiameter, index });}

    <h1>Result = @invokeMethod</h1>
```

If I manually put values in for the parameters (surfacePower, lensDiameter, index) this works fine.

The problem I'm having is looping through the dynamically created TextBoxes and retrieving the values.

The overall goal of this page is to dynamically create TextBoxes based on whichever math formula a user chooses. After they fill in the TextBoxes and hit the "Calculate" button, they'll see the result.

I didn't want to create 80 different pages, so it seemed like reflection was the way to go.

How do I loop through the TextBoxes and retrieve the values? I think I've tried every possible foreach loop I could think of...except of course the right one. Also, most of the searches I've done, yield looping through a specific model, which I don't really have for this.

Thanks,
R

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do but once you are in client side, the razor code will no longer work, you need a client side tool to calculate - js, or you need to post the values back to the server to do the calculations

Comment: Ok. What if I gathered the data from the form with js/jquery and then put into an array for the Invoke parameters? After I have the values, if I tie the button to the reflected method wouldn't it just perform the calculation?

Comment: Still, you cannot invoke c# methods after page has been loaded. You can collect the data, send it back with post method to an HttpPost method on your controller, and then invoke whatever you want, then send back the result to client

Comment: After the page loads and I press the button, the method invokes and gives the correct calculation. I just need to figure out how to get the values out of the text boxes and put them into the object array as the parameter object before that point.